# Verification of postgresql backups

Tags: postgresql

We have RESTORE VERIFYONLY  to check the validity of SQL Servers backups.

```
It Verifies the backup but does not restore it, and checks to see that the backup set is complete and the entire backup is readable.
```

Is there any way to do the same in  PostgreSQL?

How can we validate a logical backup in PostgreSQL without restoring it?

Comment: Not a SQL expert, but if you want to check something and only take an action based on the findings of the check, there's a `.commit()` function that does that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify that an archive produced by pg\_dump archive is OK and valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719108/how-to-verify-that-an-archive-produced-by-pg-dump-archive-is-ok-and-valid)

Comment: @Michu93: it's not duplicate of [How to verify that an archive produced by pg_dump archive is OK and valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719108/how-to-verify-that-an-archive-produced-by-pg-dump-archive-is-ok-and-valid). Question is about checking dump validity without restoring it physically.